# Log the RGB components of a color defined using xcolor syntax

Tags: color

I'd like LaTeX to print to its log the RGB components of a color that I've defined using the convenient `xcolor` syntax. E.g.,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\Huge\noindent%
I can see\\
\textbf{\color{red!30!black}Mount Resegone}\\
from my balcone.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `\tracingcolors=4`, the log will contain the desired information:

```
Package xcolor Info: Setting color `{}{0.3 0 0 rg 0.3 0 0 RG}{rgb}{0.3,0,0}' on
 input line 7.
```

Obtained from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\Huge\noindent%
I can see\\
\tracingcolors=4
\textbf{\color{red!30!black}Mount Resegone}\\
from my balcone.
\end{document}
```